# Windows Logo + Arrow Key Extension

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts

A great keyboard shortcut in Windows is <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>/<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> which makes a window take up the entire left/right half of the screen.  Is there any native way to configure windows with more shortcuts like this?

I'm not looking for anything incredible but for starters I was thinking the following would be useful:

- <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd>: Go to top-left corner of screen.
- <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>: Go to bottom-left corner of screen.
- <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd>: Go to top-right corner of screen.
- <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>: Go to bottom-right corner of screen.

More functionality would be good too like, making a window maximize the height according to its quadrant but not its width.

Comment: Congratulations! You've correctly anticipated the exact functionality available in Windows 10, with Windows Key + Shift + Up Arrow for that last one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a native way to configure this.

You can do it easily as shown in [this answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/3462/2336), especially focus to used **WinMove** command. It moves and sizes a window to given coordinates. (You actually do not need other commands shown in the answer. And you might need **SysGet** command to base your coordinates on actual screen area size before you use **WinMove**.)

On my PC I have defined actions similar to what you request, but they utilize <kbd>Windows Logo</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+arrows. <kbd>Windows Logo</kbd>+two arrows (as you request) might be more difficult to implement.